# I'm getting this.state.events.map is not a function message on console when trying to send data from spring controller to react Component

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, rest, axios

I have 2 problems:

1. I can't pass data from `@GetMapping("events/ongoingEvents")` endpoint to EventsComponent created in react, all I get when going on `localhost:3000/events/ongoingEvents` is empty blank page and console message `this.state.events.map is not a function`, I understand that `this.state.events.map is not a function` tells me that data is not an array so i can't use map() method on it but what is it then and how can I make it an array, is that what I should do even?
   Don't I in

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             events: []
        }
    }
```

set the state of a component to an array and then update it wit data from endpoint, if so then events should be an array, shouldn't it?

2. Even though in sckage.json  i added `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080",` and commented out `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")` in `allCurrentEvents()` method I still have to go to `localhost:3000` to see the result, what do I do so I can display the data from react at `localhost:8080`? Thanks in advance.

Entity class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "zdarzenia")
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter

public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_elektrowni", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private PowerPlant powerPlant;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public EventType typeOfEvent;

    @Column
    public Double powerDrop;

    @Column
    public LocalDate startDate;

    @Column
    public LocalDate endDate;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + typeOfEvent + "";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        Event event = (Event) o;
        return id != null && Objects.equals(id, event.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EventsReactControllers {

    private final EventRepository eventRepository;

    //@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping("events/ongoingEvents")
    public List<Event> allCurrentEvents() {
        return eventRepository.findAll().stream().filter(e -> e.endDate.isAfter(LocalDate.now()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


    @GetMapping("events/eventsEndingToday")
    public List<Event> eventsToday() {
        return eventRepository.findAll().stream().filter(e -> e.endDate.isEqual(LocalDate.now()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",


  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import EventsComponent from './EventsComponent';


function App() {

  return (
    <div>
          <header className="container">
             <EventsComponent />
          </header>
        </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';



const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

ApiService.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const EVENTS_API_REST_URL = "http://localhost:8080/events/ongoingEvents";

class APIService {

    getEvents(){
        return axios.get(EVENTS_API_REST_URL);
    }

}

export default new APIService();
```

EventsComponent.js

```
import React from 'react'
import APIService from './APIService'

export default class EventsComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             events: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        APIService.getEvents().then(({data}) => {
            this.setState({ events: data })
            console.log(this.state.data)
          })
          .catch(function (ex) {
              console.log('Response parsing failed. Error: ', ex);
          });;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 className="text-center">Events Details</h2>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Event Id</th>
                            <th>Event type</th>
                            <th>Power drop</th>
                            <th>End Date</th>
                            <th>Start date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            this.state.events.map(event =>
                                    <tr key={event.id}>
                                        <td>{event.id}</td>
                                        <td>{event.typeOfEvent}</td>
                                        <td>{event.powerDrop}</td>
                                        <td>{event.startDate}</td>
                                        <td>{event.endDate}</td>
                                    </tr>
                            )
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Security calss

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;


import javax.sql.DataSource;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/allUsers").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/users/delete/{id}").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")//albo /users/delete* przy @RequestParam
                .antMatchers("/users/update/{id}").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/delete/powerPlants/{id}").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/addEventToPlant/{plantId}/{eventId}").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/powerPlantsIds").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/regist*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/powerPlants", true);
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .logoutUrl("/logout");
    }

    ////////////
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
    ////////////


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/icon/**");
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT u.login, u.password,1 FROM user AS u WHERE u.login=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT u.login, r.typ_roli, 1 " +
                        "FROM user u " +
                        "INNER JOIN user_role ur ON ur.user_id = u.user_id " +
                        "INNER JOIN role r ON r.role_id = ur.role_id " +
                        "WHERE u.login=?")
                .dataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Terminal

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

Compiled with warnings.                                                                                                
                                                                                                                       
Warning                                                                                                                
(6:29521) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.
                                                                                                                       
Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.                                                              
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.                                                         
js.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!
../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(6:29521) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust sho
rthand is currently deprecated.

webpack compiled with 1 warning
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

Compiled with warnings.                                                                                                
                                                                                                                       
Warning                                                                                                                
(6:29521) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.
                                                                                                                       
Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.                                                              
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.                                                         
js.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!
../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(6:29521) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust sho
rthand is currently deprecated.

webpack compiled with 1 warning
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

Compiled with warnings.                                                                                                
                                                                                                                       
Warning                                                                                                                
(6:29521) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.
                                                                                                                       
Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.                                                              
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.                                                         
js.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!
../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(6:29521) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust sho
rthand is currently deprecated.

webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

Console log

```
EventsComponent.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: this.state.events.map is not a function
    at EventsComponent.render (EventsComponent.js:38:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
render @ EventsComponent.js:38
finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19752
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19698
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21611
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
EventsComponent.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: this.state.events.map is not a function
    at EventsComponent.render (EventsComponent.js:38:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
render @ EventsComponent.js:38
finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19752
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19698
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21611
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <EventsComponent> component:

    at EventsComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:217:5)
    at header
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25892
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
EventsComponent.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: this.state.events.map is not a function
    at EventsComponent.render (EventsComponent.js:38:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
render @ EventsComponent.js:38
finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19752
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19698
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21611
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
```

Comment: This does nothing `console.log(this.state.data)`

Comment: Did you check your endpoints in the network tab or postman?

Comment: @Konrad You mean if it even works? Yes I checkd and it returns some data

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Konrad i return it in the json format uing Responsebody annotation on the endpoint method and there are no errors

Comment: Try changing this `APIService.getEvents().then((data) => {` to `APIService.getEvents().then(({data}) => {`

Comment: @Konrad nothing's changed

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250775/discussion-between-ign-and-konrad).

Comment: @Konrad message is to long so I sent it to you in chat

Comment: `APIService.getEvents().then(({data}) => {` still doesn't work?

Comment: @Konrad no, I configured cors and then got ths message

Comment: in the questio i edited logs so there is the complete message

Comment: `this.state.events` is not an array